# In bash instead of creating new line changing the already made line

Tags: bash, shell-script

Ok hard to explain in few words so

I was wondering how instead of creating a new line......like lets say I want to:

```
while true; do echo "hello"; sleep 1; done
```

then I want it to count the number of times it goes through, but instead of it repeating on the next line it just changes it

Would that need some drawing scripting like x11

```
while true; do echo "hello $(date +%S)"; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Use a carriage return `\r`.

Comment: ^^^ Yeah it was